# Boost Libraries Linking Issues

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, ubuntu-11.10

I am facing few problems while linking with boost libraries. I am trying to execute [simple timer program](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer1/src.html44)

But when I execute the program getting below errors

```
~/boost_1_48_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/posix_tss_ptr.ipp:34: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
./timer.o: In function `~posix_tss_ptr': /~/boost_1_48_0/boost/asio/detail/posix_tss_ptr.hpp:48: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete' 
./timer.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr<boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::thread_info>::context>::operator boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::thread_info>::context*() const': ~/boost_1_48_0/boost/asio/detail/posix_tss_ptr.hpp:54: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
./timer.o: In function `~posix_tss_ptr': ~/boost_1_48_0/boost/asio/detail/posix_tss_ptr.hpp:48: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've included `_I ~/boost_1_48_0/ -L ~/boost_1_48_0/stage/lib -lboost-system`

Any quick pointers on this?

Comment: what happens if you link with `-lboost_thread` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you remember to specify `-pthread` as well? From GCC manpage:

> ```
>    -pthread
>        Add support for multithreading using the POSIX threads library.
>        This option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker.
> ```

It is required with code that uses POSIX threads.

Comment: Obviously assuming you're using GCC in the first place.

Comment: Thanks reko_t, I have included and it worked fine one. But, I am facing now runtime error saying libboost_system.so.1.48.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. Which is actually existing in /stage/lib directory. I am missing something to include somewhere. I am using Eclipse CDT and trying to run there.

Comment: Your system must be able to find the shared libraries from the set of given paths. If your shared library is in a non-standard directory, you can include that directory in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. Do: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/stage/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` and then try again.

Comment: No luck again, my LD_LIBRARY_PATH had no value and now I set the stage path correctly still its throwing same error. Any alternative?